# Data-Driven MsTest - Tests always show Aborted

Tags: mstest

I have what I thought was a pretty simple requirement for taking the connection string for a data-driven test and adding it to the app.config. Here was my original DataSource attribute on the test:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "MyConnectionString", "MyTable", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
```

That works perfectly. Now I add this to the app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Portal" connectionString="SameConnectionStringAsAbove" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="MyDataSource" connectionString="Portal" dataTableName="MyTable" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
</configuration>
```

And change my datasource on the test to:

```
[DataSource("MyDataSource")]
```

Now when I run my tests they just show as aborted - no error, no info in the output window. Nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Answering in case anyone else gets this issue. Just needed to change the visualstudioversion to 10:

```
<section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection,
           Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework,
           Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
           PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```